# Getting error "ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key" on Firefox

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate

I have a live video website and have recently installed SSL certificate on my video servers. I am having video playback issue on Firefox. On other browsers (Chrome, IE), everything is alright.

Example page: https://www.janjua.tv/cnn_livestreaming

While debugging the network, I noticed the video is not being played due to the error "ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key" (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dfWV.jpg).

I have Wildcard SSL from Comodo, and had generated my CSR using the guide available here: https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/keystore-jks-keytool-csr-generation-ssl-installation-guide/

My video servers are Tomcat/Java so I had to import the entire chaining path of my SSL Certificate in the following order: Root > Intermediate > SSL Certificate (using the guide available here: https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/troubleshooting-advanced-tomcat-x509-failed-to-establish-chain-from-reply/).

I have successfully installed the SSL on my video servers and video is working perfectly on browsers other than Firefox. I'm trying to understand what I'm actually missing during the CSR, Key or installation which caused the error "ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key" on Firefox and prevented the playback.

Comment: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html suggests trying the [SSL Labs SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) on the problematic domain to see if it reports any problems. But it sounds like you should be OK, unless you've accidentally ended up with a weak prime? (I went to your link to see if I could find the domain myself - it's not completely visible in your screenshot - but got a pop-up advert for escorts when I clicked play :-( )

Comment: This is domain name of video server: https://2201.janjuaplayer.com:8088/    Port 8088 is unfortunately not supported on SSL Labs.

Comment: You can try testing using https://tls.imirhil.fr/tls  It allows to specify the port. But right now it does not seem 8088 replies with TLS handshake.